# ext gwt grid event

Tags: java, gwt, event-handling, gxt

how do i get a cell value in GridEvent when clicking on a certain row.

I want to vave something like: (look at the Wishful thinking):

```
grid.addListener(Events.RowDoubleClick, new Listener<BaseEvent>() {

                @Override
                public void handleEvent(BaseEvent be) {
                    GridEvent gr = (GridEvent) be;

                    //Wishful thinking
                    String cellData = gr.getRow(gr.getRowIndex()).getCellValue("id")

                }

            });
```

Thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gr.getGrid().getView().getCell(gr.getRowIndex(),colNum)
```

If you have a BeanModel linked to the grid you can just do

```
gr.getModel().get("propertyName")
```

Comment: I had to do this to get the cell value. But agian your answered brought me 99.9% near to the solution. My code looks

Answer (score 1):

I suggest use:

```
var selectedText=grid_plancode.getView().getCell(overRow, overCell).innerText
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is listening for changes to the grid's selection model

```
grid.getSelectionModel().addListener(Events.SelectionChange,
    new Listener<SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData>>() {
        public void handleEvent(SelectionChangedEvent<ModelData> be) {
        List<ModelData> selection = be.getSelection());
        }
    });
```

"selection" would then contain a list of the ModelData objects for the selected row/s can then get the do

```
modelData.get("propertyName")
```

on each to get the value.